# Should "latest activity" on Area51 also include new comments?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

For example, latest activity on the [Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) proposal is now "5 days ago" even though a new comment was added yesterday. In my opinion a new comment is something noteworthy for me as a follower and something that indicates progress, so it should be included in the definition of "activity".

*Edit*: To clarify, I am talking about the general comments section at the top of the proposal.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't. Comment is a ease way to create fake activity to keep proposal live. Just a new follower, new question added or votes should be considered as *real* activity. Count comments as activity is to reward bad behavior.

Some proposals are live because one or two users posted comments criticizing the proposal and ask to close it. This behavior keep the proposal as a living-dead.